# How to convert each row in data frame to a node with attributes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, networkx

Given a sample data frame `df`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'a': [55, 2123, -19.3, 9, -8], 
    'b': ['aa', 'bb', 'ad', 'kuku', 'lulu']
})
```

Now I want to "upload" this data to a graph. Every row should be a node with `id`, `a`, and `b` attributes.

I have tried to do this with `from_pandas_dataframe` `NetworkX` method.

Please advise which function is responsible to do this in `NetworkX`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html) function requires **both the source and target**.

```
from networkx import nx
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='id', target='col_target')
```

You could use a loop to generate the graph:

```
from networkx import nx
G = nx.Graph()

for i, attr in df.set_index('id').iterrows():
    G.add_node(i, **attr.to_dict())
```

Or, with `from_pandas_edgelist`, if you really want only the nodes, you might want to add a dummy target:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.assign(target='none'),
                            source='id', target='target',
                            edge_attr=['a', 'b'])
```

[image]

Then remove the dummy node:

```
G.remove_node('none')
```

[image]